# Random a number in php from 10 to 100 in php

Tags: php

I would like to write a function which will print a array with a random numbers from 10 to 100 but exclude every number which counts on 5(for example 5,10,15,20 etc.).
It should print 50 numbers. I know how to print random numbers from 10 to 100, but how to exclude some of them.

My code here:

```
function getArray($myLength,$min,$max){
    $arr=array();
    for ($i=0;$i<$myLength;$i++){
        $arr[$i]=mt_rand($min,$max);
   }
    return $arr;
}
function printArray($array){
   foreach($array as $value){
        echo $value, " ";
    }
   echo "<br>";
}
$a=10;
$z=100;
$xz=50;

$myArray=getArray($xz,$a,$z);
printArray($myArray);
```

Any ideas how to exclude numbers from this array?

Comment: Use an `if` statement that checks if the number is a multiple of `5` and skips it.

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble with? Do you know how to check for multiples of a number using the `%` operator?

Comment: @Barmar no sir, no idea about % operator.

Comment: What kind of sadist would give you an assignment like this without teaching the requirements?

Comment: @Barmar I was thinking that I can pass it easily, but no way :D that's why im here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `%` operator to test if the number is a multiple of `5`?

```
function printArray($array){
   foreach($array as $value){
        if ($value % 5 != 0) {
            echo $value, " ";
        }
    }
   echo "<br>";
}
```

`%` returns the remainder when dividing numbers. Multiples of `5` will have a remainder of `0`, so this prints all the other numbers.

Comment: This way you will be not consistently printing 50 numbers. Move the condition to the generation function